# Could not load UI with data during async action from localstorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

When I click on a certain "task", it loads correctly, and displays the correct UI with data. The error occurs precisely when clicking on the link through the browser input window - `localhost:port/task/edit/id`, or when I manually refresh the page of each "task". How can I resolve this issue?

router.js:

```
{
            path: '/task/edit/:id',
            name: 'edit-task',
            component: EditView,
},
```

Sample of code, with EditView:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <task-edit :task="task" v-if="task" :key="taskId"/>
    <p v-else>Loading task...</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'EditView',
  components: {
    TaskEdit,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['tasks']),
    taskId() {
      return this.$route.params.id;
    },
    task() {
      return this.tasks.find((task) => task.id === this.taskId);
    },
  },
  async created() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('retrieveTaskById');
  },
};
</script>
```

store.js with actions for loading tasks:

```
...
  retrieveTaskById({ state }, taskId) {
        console.log('Loading task from localStorage...');
        state.tasks.find(task => {
            console.log(task.id, 'Task loaded')
            return task.id === taskId
        });
    },
...
```

Here is the output of console.logs when i manually navigate to the "edit" page:

> Loading tasks from localStorage...

Here is the output when I navigate from "home" page:

> Loading task from localStorage...
> 1 'Task loaded'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only proble I could figure out in your code snippet is that you weren't passing the taskId to the action '*retrieveTaskById*'. However I fixed it and made some improvements.

```
// State
retrievedTaskById: {}

// Mutation
setRetrievedTaskById({ state }, payload) {
    state.retrievedTaskById = payload
}

// Action
retrieveTaskById({ commit }, taskId) {
    const task = state.tasks.find(task => task.id === taskId);
    commit('setRetrievedTaskById', task)
}

// Getter
retrievedTaskById({ state }) {
    return state.retrievedTaskById
}
```

---

```
<template>
  <div>
    <task-edit :task="task" v-if="task" :key="taskId"/>
    <p v-else>Loading task...</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'EditView',
  components: {
    TaskEdit,
  },
  computed: {
    taskId() {
      return this.$route.params.id
    },
    task() {
      return this.$store.getters.retrievedTaskById
    }
    // Same: ...mapGetters(['retrievedTaskById']),
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('retrieveTaskById', this.taskId)
  }
};
</script>
```